# Run Jmeter using ant not working - jmeter jar not found

Tags: ant, jmeter

I am facing an issue for a long time. I want to create html with full Jmeter reports.
the only solution is using ant, to run jmeter according some sites.

1. I installed ant
2. navigate to C:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras and copy all the files (using ctrl +A) + (Ctrl +C)
3. Navigate to C:\ant\ant\bin and paste all the files (Ctrl +v)
4. Creating a new text file and called it Test.txt in C:\ant\ant\bin
5. Change the name of the file and called it Test.jtl
6. Under C:\ant\ant\bin I opened the build.xml file
7. I put in `-Djmeter.home=`.. - C:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0
8. I put in  `<property name="jmeter.home" value=`"C:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0/.."/>
9. I opened command line and wrote: cd C:\ant\ant\bin
   10.than the command set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin

I got error build failed C:\ant\ant\bin.xml:89:jmeter jar file not found or not a vaild file c:\jmeter_4.0\bin\ApachJmeter.jar

I know this is a long question but I am facing it for a long time. hopefully jmeter or someone will make plugin or something to do it easier, just to see all the results in html in one place.

can someone advise what I am missing?

** I noticed that Jmeter.jar exists in the error location, so I do not understand what more need to add.

[[image]][copy form jmeter extras]

[[image]][copied to ant bin folder]

[[image]][create Test.jtl file in ant/bin]

[[image]][Modified build.xml in ant bin]

[[image]][Run command and get errors]

[[image]][Jmeter jar exists]

[image]

Comment: I havent used ant so I am not putting this as an answer. But, path that error shows is different then your actual path on the system..Error:-C:\Jmeter_4.0\bin\ApacheJmeter.jar but in actual it is location C:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar.....seems like need to fix the path. But, this is just an observation and you can check.

Comment: Hey sunny can you be more specific? what to change and where? in the build.xml file? in the folder? remove Jmeter and installed fresh? can you please provide full explanation

Comment: Sunny I attached new pic, and the place of the jar file is                                C:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin  and the ant is searching in different path, can you please explain hot to change the ant path location?

Comment: hey sunny I changed the build.xml and manage to overcome this issue, the problem is that now jtl file not save any results and it is empty, so I opened an new question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549948/jtl-file-is-empty-when-running-jmeter-using-ant

Comment: instead of copying jmeter files to ant's bin directory, set your PATH to contain ant's bin directory (as described here https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) . Then `cd` to jmeter and run `ant` there

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see you're applying your point 7.
2. Your point 8 is pointing to the wrong location

You should be running your test as:

```
ant -Djmeter.home=c:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0
```

or alternatively you can hard-code path to your JMeter installation into your *build.xml* file like:

```
<property name="jmeter.home" value="C:/Jmeter_4.0/apache-jmeter-4.0"/>
```

When you override property value using `-D` command-line argument there Ant doesn't the properties defined in the *build.xml* file into consideration, it will use what you pass in the command line. See [Properties and PropertyHelpers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) Ant User Manual chapter for more details.

Going forward I would recommend you adding `jmeterlogfile` parameter to `jmeter` task like:

```
 <jmeter
    jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
    testplan="${testpath}/${test}.jmx"
    resultlog="${testpath}/${test}.jtl"
    jmeterlogfile="/path/to/jmeter.log">
```

This way you will be able to get *jmeter.log* file generated at the defined location, in the majority of cases it will help to troubleshoot the issue. More information: [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)